# So, why did Ultimecia want to compress time?

Tags: time-travel, final-fantasy

On disc three of Final Fantasy VIII, when Dr. Odine finally gets around to explaining what's going on with Ultimecia, he tells us that she's attempting to use Ellone to compress time. But maddeningly, he never tells us *why*.

We see the effects on early disc four - strange physics, and the ability to experience things across different historical periods - but it's not clear why that's Ultimecia's objective.

Are any reasons ever hinted anywhere else in the game or the Ultimania Canon?

Comment: You MIGHT have better luck with this on one of the Game Stack Exchange sites.  Just a thought.

Comment: @KHW - somehow, that thought hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: @KHW This question is about plot and not about game play, isn't it? So it's on-topic here and off-topic on Gaming.

Comment: @Gilles - Oh, sure.. Just thought he might find a bigger audience familiar with it there.  Or, more likely, on their meta or chat site.  I don't think there's anything wrong the question being asked here, just trying to point him to an additional resource.  We are probably the 'right' place to ask it.. but there are often more resources somewhere else.. *shrug*  Just trying to be helpful :)

Comment: @KHW Questions about plot have always had a somewhat nebulous presence on Gaming.SE. I'm not entirely sure *anyone* has a definite answer on where they should belong.

Comment: @Yawus - Oh, no argument -- and Giles is right, they SHOULD belong here, in the sense that they are asking about the SciFi Plot elements.. But the reason I tried to direct the questioner to Gaming as well is simply that I doubt there will be enough familiarity with it here; I point you to the lack of responses :)  -- Realizing that it may not be a perfect fit for Gaming, I was more concerned with finding an answer, than with making sure it was being asked at the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, world domination. Ultimecia is trying to compress time, condensing all of space and time into one area with herself at the center. She will absorb the power of other sorceresses from many other generations to give her great power.
She will absorb the entire universe and then recreate it according to her wishes.
Quote from the game: "A sorceress trying to change the world by compressing 
time and taking power from all sorceresses."